# How to make space visible in between an unsorted list in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have created an unsorted list/list that I would like the lines in between each word to show... so far I have this:`

```css
#header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
#navbar {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 0.8em;
  padding-left: 31em;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: ;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
}
li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0.4em;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: "Century Gothic";
  font-size: 100%;
```

```html
<img id="header" src="images/headerfit.png" />
<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.dimatteos.com.au">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.dimatteos.com.au/cucina">CUCINA</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.dimatteos.com.au/espresso">ESPRESSO</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.dimatteos.com.au/bar">BAR</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.dimatteos.com.au/functions">FUNCTIONS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.dimatteos.com.au/contact">CONTACT</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How do I make it so there is a line between each word (the space)... thankyou.

Comment: Can you clarify what it is you want? You want more space between the menu items?

Comment: I would like a line to be between each word in the list.

Comment: so the words are below eachother?

Comment: No, I would like the space between the words to be replaced with an actual visible line that separates the words.

Comment: @user3398922: The words are floated, so they are in a line.
For Cooper Timewell: use a border (for example: border-right: 1px solid white) to display a line on each elements's right side. For last element hide the border by selecting only last element with css and make border:0 none for this element.

Comment: @ynnus: Excuse me I must have read to fast. I've added an jsfiddle for him

Comment: If you have your answer please accept and upvote the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need border for your list:

```
li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0.4em;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;  
}
li:last-child {
  border-right: none;  
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4s2ho1kj/2/

Comment: if it's what you need, accept the and vote up the answer

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood you right (not sure that i have) what you want is space between each word you could do this by saying

```
li{
margin-left:10px;
} 
li:first-child{
margin-left:0px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I must have wrote the question too broad, I would like a line in between each word in the list.

Answer (score -1):

This way you will make the line that you want by adding a border to the right side of each menu item except the last.

```
li { border-right: 1px solid #000000; }
li:last-child { border-right: none }
```

here in this jsfiddle you can see what you need and try adjusting it a little till how you want it:

http://jsfiddle.net/9qdefux6/

Comment: `li:last` isn't a valid CSS pseudo-class; you (presumably) mean: `li:last-child`.

Comment: Your jsfiddle proves, instead, that it does not work.